# In 20.04 I changed format from fat32 to ext4 and now permissions are root only? Help?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, hard-drive

Ok I started having trouble with these giant video files refusing to copy to my samsung 1tb drive.  It would get to 4 GB then poof crash.  Some files are 8 GB.  I discovered the SSD was formated to the old fat32 standard and this explained the problem.  So I copied off everything and used gparted to change the format to ext4 for linux, right? Done but now no can use.  Under permissions it's all grayed out and it root:root.  I tries the chown trick and nothing ......... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: * I tries the chown trick and nothing...* You tries incorrectly then because that is what it needs. Next time format the partitions with Disks and you won't have that problem.

Comment: You can also link folders into /home so they look like they are in /home, but really in your data partition(s). Also shows example of chroot & chown which should only be used on data partitions, never on system partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Thanks old Fred.  This is a separate ssd 1 TB so how do I do that?  I need user permission.  Really thanks and Mahalo!